# Was there a wedding scene deleted from the Twilight Zone episode "Jess-Belle"?

Tags: the-twilight-zone

"[Jess-Belle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jess-Belle)" is the less famous of Anne's Francis's two star turns on *The Twilight Zone*.  In it, she plays a vindictive woman, who becomes a witch as part of her attempts to win back her ex-boyfriend.

When I saw a rerun of this episode around 1990, my mother was certain that there was a scene missing.  She had seen the episode as a teenager, when it was first broadcast in 1963.  (She definitely remembered the correct episode, since she was able to fill me in on what happened in the first few minutes, which we missed.)  However, I have seen the story several times since then, and the scene my mother was talking about was never present.

What she remembered was a wedding scene, where Billy-Ben Turner weds his new girl, having thrown off Jess's influence.  By this point, it is established that Jess can change into animal shapes, and my mother remembered a large spider being ominously present at the wedding.  Was there actually such a scene in the earliest broadcast(s) of this story?  Or was my mom just rememebering wrong?

Comment: The [IMDB page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0734581/plotsummary) about this episode mentions a spider present "at the ceremony"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, I remember it too.  At the alter he notices a black spider crawling up the brides dress or veil.  He goes to grab it and I think it disappeared and of course Jess-Belle is smirking in the background.  Was she a brides maid or just in the back of the chapel?  So long ago I'm not sure but that wedding scene and the spider are a definite.  One of the only Twilight Zone's I remember from a kid it had that much impact on me.